# Delete original file after using Zend_Filter_ImageSize()

Tags: zend-framework, delete-file

I am working with Zend and using Zend_Filter_ImageSize() to create a thumbnail. Everything works ok but after the thumb is created the original file is kept. 
I went through the files and I found nothing that might trigger the deletion of the original. Basically this is what I am doing:

```
$filter = new Zend_Filter_ImageSize(); 
    $output = $filter->setHeight(200) 
             ->setWidth(200)
             ->setThumnailDirectory('./uploads/thumb/')
                     ->setStrategy(new Zend_Filter_Imagesize_Strategy_Crop())
                    ->filter("./uploads/$img");
```

Is there any way to keep just the thumb and get rid of the original?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, its not supporting original file deletion.

**So you can do**
- You can add a delete function to that class, But I don't suggest it.
- You can extend the class and add the functionality to it.

Comment: Thank you @Venu. I will find a solution to it then.

Comment: After Saving the file I decided to go this:$files = glob("./uploads/*");
            if(!empty($files)){
            foreach($files as $file) {
             if(is_file($file)) { 
             unlink($file);
             $count++;

Comment: I know is not the best way to go but any original file is uploaded into the 'uploads' folder. This will delete anything in it. What you think?

Comment: yes it should work. But delete only that file as another user might just uploaded an image and this tries to delete that file,you will get an exception. OR Use try catch block around it

Comment: Will do that. Thank you again.